# Google Sheets not receiving json data properly from Woocommerce Webhook

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I hope you guys are having a wonderful day.

I have set up a webhook in my woocommerce that sends JSON data to Google sheets. The webhook has been working great for months now, just today, I am having some trouble with it. I have tracked the issue to be in google sheets receiving the JSON data, but I don't know why this is happening.

Let me explain.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18G-yVDjYeccl6kznpZgSuRTysRMAu57pwY2oGf6-KWI/edit?usp=sharing

This is the google sheet, when it gets Woocommerce JSON data, it populates a new row.

**The problem**

Sometimes google sheets doesn't populate the row upon receiving a new order. The problem doesn't lie with woocommerce, because I have checked woocommerce with reqbin and the webhook fires with every order.

Furthermore, when I send requests from reqbin.com to my sheet, the sheet performs the operation successfully 5-6 out of 10 times. Other times it shows an error.

**The Error**

The error is due to google sheets not being able to parse JSON data, because the JSON data it receives 5 out of 10 times is not proper JSON data. Other 5 times, it is just as it should be. I have put a catch statement if the sheet is unable to parse JSON. Instead of appending new row with the parsed data, it appends the raw received data to the sheet.

It is clear now that there is some issue with google sheets handling that JSON data because when the same data is sent from reqbin.com to webhook.site, it is perfectly as it should be 10/10 times.

**How to reproduce the issue**

- Open this google sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18G-yVDjYeccl6kznpZgSuRTysRMAu57pwY2oGf6-KWI/edit?usp=sharing
- Open reqbin.com and webhook.site, and send the following JSON from reqbin.com to webhook.site 10 times to see if any kind of error occurs.

> { "id": 47222, "parent_id": 0, "status": "processing", "currency": "PKR", "version": "5.1.0","prices_include_tax": false, "date_created": "2021-06-10T01:23:46", "date_modified": "2021-06-10T01:23:46", "discount_total": "0", "discount_tax": "0", "shipping_total": "150", "shipping_tax": "0", "cart_tax": "0", "total": "1850", "total_tax": "0", "customer_id": 0, "order_key": "wc_order_7gIuR7px6MX9C", "billing": { "first_name": "Name", "last_name": "", "company": "", "address_1": "Address", "address_2": "", "city": "City", "state": "", "postcode": "", "country": "PK", "email": "email@email.com", "phone": "1234" }, "shipping": { "first_name": "Name", "last_name": "", "company": "", "address_1": "Address", "address_2": "", "city": "City", "state": "", "postcode": "", "country": "Country" }, "payment_method": "cod", "payment_method_title": "Cash on delivery", "transaction_id": "", "customer_ip_address": "8.8.8.8", "customer_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 11; M2102J20SG) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.88 Mobile Safari/537.36", "created_via": "checkout", "customer_note": "", "date_completed": null, "date_paid": null, "cart_hash": "64d834c72eecc8e32b9d83fd67d10d9c", "number": "47222", "meta_data": [ { "id": 869388, "key": "_shipping_calculator", "value": "" }, { "id": 869389, "key": "is_vat_exempt", "value": "no" }, { "id": 869391, "key": "_wfacp_report_data", "value": { "wfacp_total": "0.00" } }, { "id": 869392, "key": "_woofunnel_cid", "value": "4" }, { "id": 869393, "key": "_wfacp_post_id", "value": "24852" }, { "id": 869394, "key": "_wfacp_source", "value": "https://website.com/checkouts/checkout-page/" }, { "id": 869395, "key": "_wfacp_timezone", "value": "Asia/Karachi" }, { "id": 869396, "key": "order_comments", "value": "" }, { "id": 869412, "key": "_new_order_email_sent", "value": "true" }, { "id": 869424, "key": "_woofunnel_custid", "value": "4" }, { "id": 869425, "key": "_pys_purchase_event_fired", "value": "1" }, { "id": 869426, "key": "_wfob_stats_ids", "value": [] }, { "id": 869427, "key": "_wfocu_thankyou_visited", "value": "yes" } ], "line_items": [ { "id": 35114, "name": "MTECH Ultra Resilient Knife", "product_id": 11074, "variation_id": 0, "quantity": 1, "tax_class": "", "subtotal": "1700", "subtotal_tax": "0", "total": "1700", "total_tax": "0", "taxes": [], "meta_data": [], "sku": "", "price": 1700, "parent_name": null } ], "tax_lines": [], "shipping_lines": [ { "id": 35115, "method_title": "Fast Shipping (2-4 Days)", "method_id": "flat_rate", "instance_id": "1", "total": "150", "total_tax": "0", "taxes": [], "meta_data": [ { "id": 275053, "key": "Items", "value": "MTECH Ultra Resilient Knife × 1", "display_key": "Items", "display_value": "MTECH Ultra Resilient Knife × 1" } ] } ], "fee_lines": [], "coupon_lines": [], "refunds": [], "date_created_gmt": "2021-06-09T20:23:46", "date_modified_gmt":"2021-06-09T20:23:46", "date_completed_gmt": null, "date_paid_gmt": null, "currency_symbol": "₨","_links": { "self": [ { "href": "https://website.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/47222" } ],"collection": [ { "href": "https://website.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders" } ] } }

- Now send the same data to the following google sheet to see if it appends the row correctly each time.

> https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxupm9bje86F4PQQkyys_LWtXs_kj279R0ipgnZ-cLd7aiEADf1AN_prhk28vOPW9JsRQ/exec

How do I solve the issue? Please let me know if you need any more information. Thanks.

**Edit:**

Instead of getting a full JSON body like mentioned above, the google sheets seems to be getting the following JSON.

```
{contextPath=, queryString=, parameter={}, postData=FileUpload, parameters={}, contentLength=3981.0}
```

I would like to know why the google sheets default parameter (e) contains this instead of a full JSON body sent to it.

**Edit # 2**

> I would like to know why the google sheets default parameter (e) contains this instead of a full JSON body sent to it.

This is because (e) has a body which will always contain those parameters. The error is due to Google Sheets receiving an empty JSON body. I am still unable to understand why this happens. When I send the same JSON to API testing sites, they always receive full JSON body. Google sheets, in some cases, does not. Why is that?

Comment: I cannot understand about `Open reqbin.com and webhook.site, and send the following JSON from reqbin.com to webhook.site 10 times to see if any kind of error occurs.`. And, although I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I cannot understand about your question. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect?

Comment: "_The error is due to..._" - What is the error message you get when this error occurs?  Can you [edit] the question to show us?

Comment: _"...the JSON data it receives 5 out of 10 times is not proper JSON data."_ If it is not valid JSON, what is it? Can you [edit] the question to show us?

Comment: And, yes, a [mre] would probably help the community to more easily help you.

Comment: @Tanaike I have edited the question. Please take another look.

Comment: @andrewjames I have edited the question. Please take another look.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Usmantastic Thank you for replying. I'm glad you can understand about the reason of the issue. About `I am still unable to understand why it gets an empty body, but when I receive those requests on api testing sites (webhook.site). They always get full body.`, I think that in this case, it might be due to the specification of API you want to use. So, for example, how about contacting to the manager of the API you want to use?

Comment: @Usmantastic Now, I noticed that your question has already been changed by `Edit # 2`. In this case, unfortunately, I understood that my answer was not useful for your situation. Because my answer is for your 1st question. So I would like to delete my answer. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. I didn't see any script/code in your sheet. How does the sheet request the JSON response? Can you show that code? Or is it some other process? (I have only seen issues like this when a process fails to wait for an async callback to finish - but I have no idea if that is relevant here).

Comment: @andrewjames The sheet doesn't request a response. There is a native google sheets function doPost(e) that accepts data from any source sending it to a sheet's webapp url. The webapp url is mentioned in the question above so you can send the data to that url from any service (postman, api testing sites etc) and it will process the information. The problem I am facing is that when I send data to my google sheet, about half of the time it reports that the body of the JSON data is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue with some trial and error. For anyone facing the same issue in the future, here is what worked for me.

I was using e.postData.contents to get the JSON body but this seems to have stopped working, which was causing the JSON body to be empty. I tried e.postData.getDataAsString(); which seems to be working just fine and the issue has been resolved.